# Using pretrained yolo model on individual images but getting no bounding boxes for my detections

Tags: python, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, yolo

I'm using utralytics YOLO model:

```
model = YOLO("yolov8x.pt")
```

I'm trying to use this model to get predictions from an individual image fed into the model. This works, however, the output I receive is as follows:

```
results = model.predict("dir of image.jpg")
```

```
image 1/1 *name of dir*: 384x640 1 clock, 1908.3ms  
Speed: 2.4ms preprocess, 1908.3ms inference, 0.9ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 384, 640)
```

I'm trying to append the 1 clock found above. This is a YOLO V8 model.

When I run `print(results)`, the output shows this:

```
[ultralytics.yolo.engine.results.Results object with attributes:

boxes: ultralytics.yolo.engine.results.Boxes object
keypoints: None
keys: ['boxes']
masks: None
names: {0: 'person', 1: 'bicycle', 2: 'car', 3: 'motorcycle', 4: 'airplane', 5: 'bus', 6: 'train', 7: 'truck', 8: 'boat', 9: 'traffic light', 10: 'fire hydrant', 11: 'stop sign', 12: 'parking meter', 13: 'bench', 14: 'bird', 15: 'cat', 16: 'dog', 17: 'horse', 18: 'sheep', 19: 'cow', 20: 'elephant', 21: 'bear', 22: 'zebra', 23: 'giraffe', 24: 'backpack', 25: 'umbrella', 26: 'handbag', 27: 'tie', 28: 'suitcase', 29: 'frisbee', 30: 'skis', 31: 'snowboard', 32: 'sports ball', 33: 'kite', 34: 'baseball bat', 35: 'baseball glove', 36: 'skateboard', 37: 'surfboard', 38: 'tennis racket', 39: 'bottle', 40: 'wine glass', 41: 'cup', 42: 'fork', 43: 'knife', 44: 'spoon', 45: 'bowl', 46: 'banana', 47: 'apple', 48: 'sandwich', 49: 'orange', 50: 'broccoli', 51: 'carrot', 52: 'hot dog', 53: 'pizza', 54: 'donut', 55: 'cake', 56: 'chair', 57: 'couch', 58: 'potted plant', 59: 'bed', 60: 'dining table', 61: 'toilet', 62: 'tv', 63: 'laptop', 64: 'mouse', 65: 'remote', 66: 'keyboard', 67: 'cell phone', 68: 'microwave', 69: 'oven', 70: 'toaster', 71: 'sink', 72: 'refrigerator', 73: 'book', 74: 'clock', 75: 'vase', 76: 'scissors', 77: 'teddy bear', 78: 'hair drier', 79: 'toothbrush'}
orig_img: array(*Numpy array of image*, dtype=uint8)
orig_shape: (1080, 1920)
path: '*dir of image*'
probs: None
save_dir: None
speed: {'preprocess': 2.1491050720214844, 'inference': 1947.8471279144287, 'postprocess': 1.3186931610107422}]
```

I'm trying to get the 1 Clock as mentioned above.
Can someone help with this or do I need to try a new model?